# Docker: Copy file out of container while building it

Tags: docker

I build the following image with `docker build -t mylambda .`
I now try to export `lambdatest.zip` to my localhost while building it so I see the .zip file on my Desktop. So far I used `docker cp <Container ID>:/var/task/lambdatest.zip ~/Desktop` but that doesn't work inside my Dockerfile (?). Do you have any ideas?

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.7
COPY lambda_function.py .

RUN python3 -m venv venv
RUN . venv/bin/activate

# ZIP
RUN pushd /var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
# Execute "zip" in bash for explanation of -9qr
RUN zip -9qr /var/task/lambdatest.zip *
```

Dockerfile (updated):

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.7
RUN python3 -m venv venv
RUN . venv/bin/activate

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pystan==2.18
RUN pip install fbprophet

WORKDIR /var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages

COPY lambda_function.py .
COPY .lambdaignore .

RUN echo "Package size: $(du -sh | cut -f1)"

RUN zip -9qr lambdatest.zip *
RUN cat .lambdaignore | xargs zip -9qr /var/task/lambdatest.zip * -x
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The typical answer is you do not. A Dockerfile does not have access to write files out to the host, by design, just as it does not have access to read arbitrary files from outside of the build context. There are various reasons for that, including security (you don't want an image build dropping a backdoor on a build host in the cloud) and reproducibility (images should not have dependencies outside of their context).

As a result, you need to take an extra step to extract contexts of an image back to the host. Typically this involves creating a container a running a `docker cp` command, along the lines of the following:

```
docker build -t your_image .
docker create --name extract your_image
docker cp extract:/path/to/files /path/on/host
docker rm extract
```

Or it can involve I/O pipes, where you run a tar command inside the container  to package the files, and pipe that to a tar command running on the host to save the files.

```
docker build -t your_image
docker run --rm your_image tar -cC /path/in/container . | tar -xC /path/on/host
```

---

Recently, Docker has been working on [buildx](https://github.com/docker/buildx) which is currently experimental. Using that, you can create a stage that consists of the files you want to export to the host and use the `--output` option to write that stage to the host rather than to an image. Your Dockerfile would then look like:

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.7 as build
COPY lambda_function.py .

RUN python3 -m venv venv
RUN . venv/bin/activate

# ZIP
RUN pushd /var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
# Execute "zip" in bash for explanation of -9qr
RUN zip -9qr /var/task/lambdatest.zip *

FROM scratch as artifact
COPY --from=build /var/task/lambdatest.zip /lambdatest.zip

FROM build as release
```

And then the build command to extract the zip file would look like:

```
docker buildx build --target=artifact --output type=local,dest=$(pwd)/out/ .
```

I believe buildx is still marked as experimental in the latest release, so to enable that, you need at least the following json entry in `$HOME/.docker/config.json`:

```
{ "experimental": "enabled" }
```

And then for all the buildx features, you will want to create a non-default builder with `docker buildx create`.

---

With recent versions of the docker CLI, integration to buildkit has exposed more options. Now it's no longer needed to run buildx to get access to the output flag. That means the above changes to:

```
docker build --target=artifact --output type=local,dest=$(pwd)/out/ .
```

If buildkit hasn't been enabled on your version (should be on by default in 20.10), you can enable it in your shell with:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
```

or for the entire host, you can make it the default with the following in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
  "features": {"buildkit": true }
}
```

And to use the `daemon.json` the docker engine needs to be reloaded:

```
systemctl reload docker
```

Comment: One more question @BMitch 
I tried to go with the approach `docker create --name extract your_image`

I just run into the problem that I receive the message `Error response from daemon: No command specified`. I updated my full docker file above.

Comment: @JoeyCoder typically an image has a command or entrypoint to run, that's required to create an image. Since you aren't running the container, you can just append something like `/bin/sh` as a final arg to the `docker create` command.

Answer (score 17):

Since docker 18.09, it natively supports a custom backend called BuildKit:

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -o target/folder myimage
```

This allows you to copy your latest stage to `target/folder`. If you want only specific files and not an entire filesystem, you can add a stage to your build:

```
FROM XXX as builder-stage
# Your existing dockerfile stages

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder-stage /file/to/export /
```

Note: You will need your docker client and engine to be compatible with Docker Engine API 1.40+, otherwise docker will not understand the `-o` flag.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#custom-build-outputs

Comment: Very concise answer, this is what I needed.